# What is the purpose of this carved wooden implement found in a pipe space?

Tags: hvac, wood, basement, pipe

(This may not be the right place to ask this, and if not, please let me know where I might go instead.)

I discovered this carved wooden cross-like thing in a basement pipe space (see picture below).  At first I thought it was some sort of symbol, but more likely it's some kind of tool or jig used in construction, though I'm uncertain of what purpose it could have.  Perhaps it had some use in the context of HVAC or plumbing.  I found it lying on a duct amidst some other debris (broken lightbulbs, insulation, etc.), so if it had a structural use at one point, it was no longer being used like that at the time I discovered it.

I'm wondering if anyone might know what this is for.

Thank you for your help, and let me know if there's any additional information I can add.

[image: wooden cross-like implement resting on duct in basement pipe space]

Comment: I think it might be closer to furniture or window/door decoration than a tool.

Comment: Maybe it was a gardening implement, where the long straight bit might have had a wooden handle.

Comment: My guess would be a hook that someone carved, and tied to rope to retrieve something that fell into the pipe chase.  My experience is that such devices never work, although when dragging an extension cord or garden hose across a lawn, it will get hopelessly entangled on every sprinkler, mailbox, free, or fencepost in the vicinity.

Comment: Put it back where you found it, unless you want to end up in a horror flick.